# Is it possible to distinguish different invocations of the same event?

Tags: c#, debugging, stack-trace

I am trying to build some debug functionality to help with tracing some code. What I want to do is group traces based on if they can be traced back to the same invocation of an event.

Say I have this:

```
public partial class StackTraceForm : Form
{
    public StackTraceForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listTraces = new List<StackTrace>();
    }

    List<StackTrace> listTraces;

    private void buttonAddTraces_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listTraces.Add(new StackTrace(true));
        listTraces.Add(new StackTrace(true));
    }
}
```

If I click buttonAddTraces twice, listTraces will contain 4 traces, with 0 and 1 coming from the first click and 2 and 3 coming from the second.

So far what I've done is crawled down the stack trace to find the first frame that comes from Windows (by checking that the source filename is blank -- works so far), then go back one to get the event handler (in this case just the top frame, buttonAddTraces). So I would like some way of telling that traces 0 and 1 came from a different invocation of buttonAddTraces than traces 2 and 3.

I could modify the event handlers, adding an incrementing static variable or something, but my project has hundreds of handlers and it's not practical to change that much code. Also that wouldn't be thread-safe.

Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: `Also that wouldn't be thread-safe.` The code is only ever running in a single thread (the UI thread) so this isn't relevant.

Comment: not a solution in on itself, but it may be a help to you: Look up PostSharp (there is a free (as in free-beer) version). It'd allow you to log a lot of things with only a few lines of code and without touching your existing codebase.

Comment: @Servy : there is also a lot of code that runs in background workers/threads which would be nice to trace as well.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler : Thanks, I will give that a try. Looks like it may do what I need.